# How can I get a specific value into SoapUI?

Tags: xpath, xquery, soapui

I have this xml response...

```
<otherDataFreetext>
<freetextDetail>
    <subjectQualifier>3</subjectQualifier>
    <type>P06</type>
</freetextDetail>
<longFreetext>PAX 057-3263559627-28/ETAF/BRL3284.98/27FEB13/SAOFJ2100/57515496</longFreetext>
```

... and I want get from 'longFreetext' the '057-3263559627' specific value.
Which is the correct XPath or XQuery I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath 2.0 (or XQuery 1.0 or newer which contains XPath as a subset) you could use tokenize to split up the sequence and reconstruct it.

```
string-join(//longFreetext/tokenize(., "[- ]")[position() = (2, 3)], "-")
```